# Weird behavior when swapping items in lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, swap

I am trying to perform swaps in a python code. I have a list that contain unique tags, which looks like this:

```
list = [0, 1, ...., N-1]
```

The swapping takes place in two for loops (one for odd, one for evens) that looks like this:

```
if odd:
    for exch in range(0, N / 2 -1 + N%2):
        index1 = list[2*exch+1]
        index2 = list[2*exch+2]
        some_conditions = function(index1, index2)
        print 'Trying to swap indexes ' + str(index1) + ' and ' + str(index2)
        if np.random.uniform(0,1) < some_conditions:
            list[index1], list[index2] = list[index2], list[index1]
            other[index1], other[index2] = other[index2], other[index1]
else:
    for exch in range(0, N / 2 ):
        index1 = list[2*exch]
        index2 = list[2*exch+1]
        some_conditions = function(index1, index2)
        print 'Trying to swap indexes ' + str(index1) + ' and ' + str(index2)
        if np.random.uniform(0,1) < some_conditions:
            list[index1], list[index2] = list[index2], list[index1]
            other[index1], other[index2] = other[index2], other[index1]
```

Somehow, when a swap takes place, python prints the same index twice in a row, reporting something like (this is true for both even and odds):

```
Trying to swap index 0 and index 1
Trying to swap index 0 and index 4
```

Given that the values of index1 and index2 are unique, how can python print something like this? In subsequent steps, the value of 0 is not reprinted twice so it is probably fine in the memory, but I can't figure why it would print twice the same index.

Am I missing something here ? For reference, this is a replica exchange calculation for molecular dynamics on MPI, but the exchange is only on rank 0. This is on python 2.7.

Edit : updated description with both odd and even swaps to make things a bit clearer. The reason as to why I have this "weird" thing is that I need to swap values which are adjacent in the other list, which corresponds to some simulation parameters. For instance, if other contains :

```
other = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

I'll try to swap 1 with 2 and 3 with 4 for the odd swap then for the even swap, ill try 2 with 3 and 4 with 5.

Comment: It looks like `index1` takes values from index 1 of list. How can it be 0? Is your list sorted the way it is shown here?

Comment: In `index1 = list[2*exch+1]`, why are you already indexing the list?

Comment: I've added a bit of description. There's two kinds of swap in there and they both have the same problem, I should have used matching problems. The reason why I index in list is that I need to perform swaps on two lists for values which were initially next to each other in list.

Comment: Too see if I understand, what would be the desired output of [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing something weird here. First of, you declare index1 and index2 as the values inside of the list, not the actual indexes.

```
index1 = list[2*exch+1]
index2 = list[2*exch+2]
```

Then, when you say

```
list[index1], list[index2] = list[index2], list[index1]
```

You're actually using index1 and index2 as indexes, when they're not actual indexes, they're the value inside the list, so for example, at first index1 will be 0 and index2 will be 1, then you swap them, the second time index1 will be whatever value you stored in list[3] and index2 will be the value in list[4].

This will solve it, as you don't actually need to store the values to change them

```
for exch in range(0, N / 2 -1 + N%2):
index1 = 2*exch+1
index2 = 2*exch+2
some_conditions = function(index1, index2)
print 'Trying to swap indexes ' + str(index1) + ' and ' + str(index2)
if np.random.uniform(0,1) < some_conditions:
    list[index1], list[index2] = list[index2], list[index1]
```

Comment: I actually need to swap indexes belonging to the list as I did before. The reason is that I need to swap indices that were initially next to each other. I'll edit the question with some additional information